# Drupal.attachBehaviors: correct argument? (javascript/jquery/Drupal 6)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-6

I'm using Drupal 6. I need to append the remove link to the dom.  Then I want to use Drupal.attachBehaviors on the remove link element that I just appended.  I am attaching behaviors to this link so that I can write more javascript to handle this link's click.  When I attach behaviors as I have below I get

**Line 10: Uncaught Type Error: Cannont call method 'replace' of undefined**

$("#edit-field-product-ref-provider-0-nid-nid", context).val() is returning null.  If I comment out the Drupal.attachBehaviors line below the error goes away and team_current has the value I expect.

1. Is what I am passing to Drupal.attachBehaviors correct?
2. Can you tell me why the Drupal.attachBehaviors line is causing an error in the var team_current line?

**HTML generated after javascript runs:**

```
<div class="form-item" id="edit-field-product-ref-provider-0-nid-nid-wrapper">

  <input type="text" name="field_product_ref_provider[0][nid][nid]" id="edit-field-product-ref-provider-0-nid-nid" size="60" value="bw11 [nid:631]" class="form-text form-autocomplete text noderelationships-nodereference-autocomplete noderelationships[field_product_ref_provider] noderelationships-processed nodeRefUi-processed" autocomplete="OFF">

  <div class="noderelationships-nodereference-buttons-wrapper">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="noderelationships-nodereference-create-button" title="Create a new support team listing and assign it to this product">Create a new support team listing and assign it to this product</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="noderelationships-nodereference-remove-button" title="Remove support team from this product" style="">Remove support team from this product</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
(function ($) {
  // Store our function as a property of Drupal.behaviors.
  Drupal.behaviors.tsrNodeRefUi = function (context) {

    var team_current = $("#edit-field-product-ref-provider-0-nid-nid", context).val().replace(/\s\[nid:\d+\]/, ''); 
    var remove_button = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="noderelationships-nodereference-remove-button" title="Remove support team from this product">Remove support team from this product</a>';

    //Add Remove link...
    $(".noderelationships-nodereference-buttons-wrapper").append(remove_button);

    //Attach Behaviors
    Drupal.attachBehaviors($(".noderelationships-nodereference-remove-button"));
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last line:

```
Drupal.attachBehaviors($(".noderelationships-nodereference-remove-button"));
```

Should be:

```
Drupal.attachBehaviors(remove_button);
```